# Logout with Angular WebApi : Error OPTIONS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logout, openiddict

When I disconnect with my angular application through my WebApi my request is rejected during the call `OPTIONS`

I use `OpenIddict` and `Asp.Net core 2.2`, and I call this method

```
[HttpGet("~/connect/logout")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    return SignOut(OpenIddictServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

I have this error

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:44300/connect/logout fail:
>   OpenIddict.Server.Internal.OpenIddictServerHandler[0]
>         The logout request was rejected because an invalid HTTP method was specified: OPTIONS. info:
>   OpenIddict.Server.Internal.OpenIddictServerHandler[0]
>         The logout response was successfully returned as a plain-text document: {
>           "error": "invalid_request",
>           "error_description": "The specified HTTP method is not valid."
>         }.

I have no problem with my other APIs

Comment: Is `OPTIONS` request disabled?
have you enabled CORS?

Comment: it's called by an angular application, I do not know how to disable OPTION when calling.
On the server side I set the CORS domain all origins all verbs ...

Comment: Are you running it on IIS? If yes, you should check out the web.config.

Comment: You could also put a breakpoint at the controller, and see is the API call successful but your server threw an exception. This was what causing the error in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact an OPTIONS request is sent - most likely a preflight CORS request in this case - makes me think you tried to use the logout endpoint as an "API endpoint", something it's not made for.

Pretty much like the authorization endpoint, the logout endpoint is an interactive endpoint, designed to be used with good old redirects, and optionally a consent screen, to inform the user he or she's about to be logged out (and thus, prevent unwanted logouts, that are usually seen as targeted "DOS" attacks).

Assuming you don't want a consent screen, consider sending the logout request in a hidden iframe, instead of using XMLHttpRequest.